# calculating an integral with respect to a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the measurable space $(\mathbb{N},P(\mathbb{N}),\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure. We then define the measure $v= \mu + \delta_2 + \delta_5$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac measure. This new measure is also a measure on the same measurable space. Furthermore we consider the integral
$\int_\mathbb{N} f dv $ where $f(n)=2^{-n}$. I am having problems computing this integral.

First of all I know that $\int_\mathbb{N} f dv =\int_\mathbb{N} f d\mu+\int_\mathbb{N} f d\delta_2  +\int_\mathbb{N} f \delta_5 $.

Since $f$ is an $v$-integral function, I wanted to find a sequence of simple functions $f_n$ s.t $f_n \nearrow f$, because I know how to integrate simple functions. Can anyone help me write such functions or maybe have a better idea to a solution?

Comment: Are you sure $f(n)=2^{-2}$, or is that a typo?

Comment: Ty! it has been corrected

Comment: Try $f_n(k)=f(k)\mathbf 1_{k\leqslant n}$.

Comment: That will not work, if I evaluate f in my variable I will not be able to pull it outside the integral. Thus I am stuck in the same situation